# Ad crap is causing browser errors, is this acceptable?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, advertising

This sort of ad stuff that tries to execute gifs and pull do all sorts of shady stuff is a big red flag for me and is making me feel uneasy using this platform. What can be done and/or how to reassure people like me?

Here's a screen capture of what's going on:

[image: ad.doubleclick.net tries to serve gif as a script]

Here's the url of the ifram of the ad.doubleclick.net advertisement:

```
https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adi/N233401.1948300STACKOVERFLOW/B9334613.127047440;dc_ver=26.68;sz=728x90;dc_adk=2027040026;ord=iof8j1;click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3D34J8f5cTDSl0wEYqZX9r6qsqv-0%26url%3D;dc_rfl=1,http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F487949%2Fubuntu-14-04-and-libdvdcss-file$0;xdt=0;crlt=SVCkqDv7o8;sttr=74;prcl=s?
```

And here's what it tries to load:

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Advertisement</title></head><body style="margin:0px;"><div class="GoogleActiveViewClass" id="DfaVisibilityIdentifier_3908210541"><a target="_blank" href="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsv-kXTyXUQrC54KIBmh0rv73Lnlw-i-PjgSl0iVzFwaGh0BsXHP-R_OcSeq6qQrWyiEaOpoLUTa6_-ip-ZjRW7g0U-I4UfhWz67bdpmkW4kufusFRgunDs&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzNaHgHfTJ6H8&amp;urlfix=1&amp;adurl=http://engine.adzerk.net/r%3Fe%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%26s%3D34J8f5cTDSl0wEYqZX9r6qsqv-0%26url%3Dhttp://www.softlayer.com/info/break-boundaries-compute%253Futm_source%253Dstackoverflow%2526utm_medium%253Dbanner%2526utm_content%253DBreak_Boundaries_White%257CTargeting%257C728x90%257CJPEG%2526utm_campaign%253DEU_-_IMT_-_English_-_Region_-_Media_Buy_-_StackOverflow_-_Awareness"><img src="https://s0.2mdn.net/viewad/5063266/3-Breaking_Boundariesv2__White__-_English_-_728x90_-JPG.jpg" alt="Advertisement" border="0" width="728" height="90"></a></div><script type="text/javascript">if (!window.mraid) {(function() {var avDiv = document.getElementById("DfaVisibilityIdentifier_3908210541");if (!avDiv) {avDiv = {};window["DfaVisibilityIdentifier_3908210541_avData"] = avDiv;}if (avDiv) {avDiv['_avi_'] = 'BeRQ-ax_4VvuuEejvyAPXibPQBgAAAAAQATgB4AQCiAXV3rkEoAY-';avDiv['_avihost_'] = 'pagead2.googlesyndication.com';avDiv['_avm_'] = 'la\x3d0\x26';}var glidar = document.createElement('script');glidar.type = 'text/javascript';glidar.async = true;glidar.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/lidar.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(glidar, s);})();} else {document.write('\x3cimg src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview?id=lidar2&avi=BeRQ-ax_4VvuuEejvyAPXibPQBgAAAAAQATgB4AQCiAXV3rkEoAY-&r=w&rs=5i" style="display:none;"\x3e\x3c/img\x3e');}</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bizibly.com/i?v=5063266&amp;a=300113198&amp;c=68034518&amp;s=%25esid!&amp;p=%25epid!&amp;m=%25m&amp;n=%25n"></script><script>(function(){var f=function(a,c,b){return a.call.apply(a.bind,arguments)},g=function(a,c,b){if(!a)throw Error();if(2<arguments.length){var d=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);return function(){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);Array.prototype.unshift.apply(b,d);return a.apply(c,b)}}return function(){return a.apply(c,arguments)}},k=function(a,c,b){k=Function.prototype.bind&&-1!=Function.prototype.bind.toString().indexOf("native code")?f:g;return k.apply(null,arguments)};var l=document,m=window;var n=function(a){return{visible:1,hidden:2,prerender:3,preview:4}[a.webkitVisibilityState||a.mozVisibilityState||a.visibilityState||""]||0},p=function(a){var c;a.mozVisibilityState?c="mozvisibilitychange":a.webkitVisibilityState?c="webkitvisibilitychange":a.visibilityState&&(c="visibilitychange");return c};var r=function(){this.g=l;this.j=m;this.i=!1;this.h=[];this.m={};if(3==n(this.g)){var a=k(this.o,this);this.n=a;var c=this.g,b=p(this.g);c.addEventListener?c.addEventListener(b,a,!1):c.attachEvent&&c.attachEvent("on"+b,a)}else q(this)};r.p=function(){return r.l?r.l:r.l=new r};var s=/^([^:]+:\/\/[^/]+)/m,t=/^\d*,(.+)$/m,q=function(a){if(!a.i){a.i=!0;for(var c=0;c<a.h.length;++c)a.k.apply(a,a.h[c]);a.h=[]}};r.prototype.q=function(a,c){var b=c.target.t();(b=t.exec(b))&&(this.m[a]=b[1])};r.prototype.k=function(a,c){var b;if(b=this.s)i:{try{var d=s.exec(this.j.location.href),e=s.exec(a);if(d&&e&&d[1]==e[1]&&c){var h=k(this.q,this,c);this.s(a,h);b=!0;break i}}catch(y){}b=!1}b||(b=this.j,b.google_image_requests||(b.google_image_requests=[]),d=b.document.createElement("img"),d.src=a,b.google_image_requests.push(d))};r.prototype.o=function(){if(3!=n(this.g)){q(this);var a=this.g,c=p(this.g),b=this.n;a.removeEventListener?a.removeEventListener(c,b,!1):a.detachEvent&&a.detachEvent("on"+c,b)}};var u=function(a,c){var b=/(google|doubleclick).*\/pagead\/adview/.test(a),d=r.p(),e=a;if(b){b="&vis="+n(d.g);c&&(b+="&ve=1");var h=e.indexOf("&adurl"),e=-1==h?e+b:e.substring(0,h)+b+e.substring(h)}d.i?d.k(e,c):d.h.push([e,c])},v=["pdib"],w=this;v[0]in w||!w.execScript||w.execScript("var "+v[0]);for(var x;v.length&&(x=v.shift());)v.length||void 0===u?w=w[x]?w[x]:w[x]={}:w[x]=u;})();pdib("https://googleads4.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/view?xai\x3dAKAOjsv-kXTyXUQrC54KIBmh0rv73Lnlw-i-PjgSl0iVzFwaGh0BsXHP-R_OcSeq6qQrWyiEaOpoLUTa6_-ip-ZjRW7g0U-I4UfhWz67bdpmkW4kufusFRgunDs\x26sig\x3dCg0ArKJSzPZQ914N6lEhEAE\x26urlfix\x3d1\x26adurl\x3d");</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {if (!window.GoogleTyFxhY || typeof window.GoogleTyFxhY.push !== 'function') {window.GoogleTyFxhY = [];}window.GoogleTyFxhY.push({'_scs_': 'BtWsXax_4VvuuEejvyAPXibPQBgAAAAA4AeAEAg','_bgu_': 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/bg/F5EcQNuXvzCwnROrenDy46C3KsouVqfn29hTt0MreZk.js','_bgp_': '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\x3d'});var gsodar = document.createElement('script');gsodar.type = 'text/javascript';gsodar.async = true;gsodar.src = '//tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sbhK2lTE.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(gsodar, s);})();</script></body></html>
</code>
```

Full saved site snapshot of the advertisement:
[snapshot of the ad link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3B3w2fpuRvkOGpMaEtGdEp6Ync&usp=sharing)

Here's full saved site snapshot of the askubuntu page:
[askubuntu question snapshot](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3B3w2fpuRvkTXRfdzNIVXFsMHc&usp=sharing)

Of particular interest is the iframe with id ados_frame_adzerk628805609_972231 where the advertisement ultimately loads inside another iframe. Here is the end results of the nodes loaded in DOM after all requests have completed:

```
<iframe id="ados_frame_adzerk628805609_972231" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="90" width="728">
<html><head><style>div,iframe { top: 0; position:absolute; }</style></head><body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"><script type="text/javascript">var divName = "adzerk628805609";var inFIF=true;var inDapIF = true;</script><ins class="dcmads" style="display: inline-block; width: 728px; height: 90px; text-decoration: none;" data-dcm-placement="N233401.1948300STACKOVERFLOW/B9334613.127047440" data-dcm-rendering-mode="iframe" data-dcm-https-only="" data-dcm-click-tracker="http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&amp;s=34J8f5cTDSl0wEYqZX9r6qsqv-0&amp;url=" data-dcm-processed="y">
  <script src="//www.googletagservices.com/dcm/dcmads.js"></script><script src="http://www.googletagservices.com/dcm/impl_v26.js"></script><iframe src="https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adi/N233401.1948300STACKOVERFLOW/B9334613.127047440;dc_ver=26.68;sz=728x90;dc_adk=2027040026;ord=iof8j1;click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3D34J8f5cTDSl0wEYqZX9r6qsqv-0%26url%3D;dc_rfl=1,http%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F487949%2Fubuntu-14-04-and-libdvdcss-file$0;xdt=0;crlt=SVCkqDv7o8;sttr=74;prcl=s?" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></iframe>
</ins></body></html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Your screenshot suggests the advertisement is hidden in that "Answered X minutes ago " ( or whatever time/date  ) text . I've never had it and it shows up for me as plain text.

Comment: SE doesn't use doubleclick for ads. You're either using bad DNS or you have a nasty extension installed.

Comment: SE uses adzerk: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238387/270345. One possibility is that your ISP could be inserting ads.

Comment: Ah, sorry the screen capture is perhaps a bit misleading. The targeted element is in no way relevant here, it's just the console log entry that is meaningful. I'll fix it since I still have it open on my tabs.

Comment: Stack Exchange does not use these companies/URLs. You're not getting them from the site.

Comment: @Seth, are you sure adzerk doesn't sometimes use third party advertisers like ad.doubleclick.com? I find it quite difficult to believe that Finnish ISPs would swap askubuntus SEs advertisements to something more of their liking. Likewise I'm finding it difficult to believe the problem would be in their/my DNS. What it comes to extensions I do not have any extensions installed except for Ember Inspector and Google docs, cast and docs offline all of which I'm quite sure are safe to use.

Comment: Stack Exchange is very strict in what advertising they use. They're the only company I've found that even has a contingency plan for users in case they someday go rogue.. So, yes, I'm sure. I'll ping an SE dev to take a look in case this is happening and they don't know, but it is very very unlikely. They probably won't respond until the weekend ends.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213770/203389

Comment: I'll attach the full html page for the askubuntu question, but looking at the source it looks like adzerk loaded inside it's iframe another iframe from another advertisement provider.

Comment: If you don't want to see the ads, whoever and why ever they are coming, you should just use an extension such as Ad Block Plus.

Comment: The ads on SE are all static images. And for me, adzerk loads no iframes. There's just a regular div with an img for the image, plus a couple of divs for voting buttons.

Comment: This isn't a problem on Stack Exchange's end. It's somewhere either on your machine or between your machine and the SE servers - not only does Stack Exchange never serve animated ads, nobody else seems to be able to reproduce this.

Comment: @TimoLehto: you're not seeing the ad animate, correct? I don't see it animate either, but I don't think that's your concern. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Also: you all are correct, we are *exceptionally* strict about what kind of advertisements we allow on SE, but DoubleClick is not necessarily a questionable source. It simply hosts creatives for which they generate creative tags which we then upload to Adzerk, our server, who kindly delivers the creatives to SE. If there is a something malicious going on here (which is unclear to me as yet), it won't be just bc the creative is coming from DoubleClick. More important: **can anyone repro the error?**

Comment: @muru, obviously the ads are tailored to each individual and whatever information they have about you. With incognito I get a different ad, this time without errors, but the structure is about the same and the end source is ad.doubleclick.net, but ofcourse they still know my ip at least so they know something about me, so you might get different add.

Comment: @TimoLehto It's obvious whoever's injecting ads in your case is tracking you. But I don't see anything of that kind here. Just for the sake of it, I tried with Firefox's incognito mode over Tor … and oddly enough, I stopped seing ads altogether.

Comment: @stevvve I don't see nor do I expect to see any animations. The add displays "correct" for what I can tell, but apparently tries to load a gif as a script at some point.  I tried with another computer using incognito (though with same internet) and was able to reproduce after a couple of refreshes. Whether this is a serious security concern or a minor bug on adzerk/doublecliks side or something else I do not know.

Comment: @muru, yeah that's the name of the game today. Everybody's tracking everybody and that's fine, it's business as usual. The thing that I don't like is when an advertiser tries to do something the browser deems illegal, like executing gifs as scripts.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know! I've reached out to the advertiser to let them know about the error and I'll update here when it's resolved or I have more info. (FYI, I work on the SO Ad Ops team with stevvve).

---

Update: The advertiser has removed the troublesome Bizible tag completely, so we shouldn't be seeing this error anymore.